# Storing newline separated strings into array with bash

Tags: arrays, bash, command-line, scripting, sh

I have the following code

```
tasks=$(cut ~/.todo/data -f3)
```

data consists of

```
1331956800  29  task 5
1361077200  28  task 3
1363554894  26  task 1
1363555119  30  baller
```

For some reason, I can extract the first two columns with this method but the third doesn't seem to work properly. I tried setting `IFS='\n'` before `tasks=` but it still refuses to work.

There are tabs between columns, only spaces in column 3.

I want

```
${tasks[0]} = "task 5"
${tasks[1]} = "task 3"
...
${tasks[3]} = "baller"
```

Here is the output of cut

```
$ cut ~/.todo/data -f3
task 5
task 3
task 1
baller
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple bash solution.

```
tasks=()
while IFS=$'\t' read _ _ t; do
        tasks+=("$t")                                                       
done <<-!
        1331956800      29      task 5
        1361077200      28      task 3
        1363554894      26      task 1
        1363555119      30      baller
!

for t in "${tasks[@]}"; do
        echo "$t"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

[awk](/questions/tagged/awk) splits columns on space or tabs by default (that can be more than just one of these) and it's more suitable for files with mixed columns delimiters.

```
readarray a < <(awk '{print "\047" $3, $4 "\047"}' file.txt)
for i in ${!a[@]}; do echo "index[$i]=${a[i]}"; done
```

**Edit** : your question grown in the thread, so

```
readarray a < <(
    awk '{$1=$2=""; sub(/^ +/, ""); print "\047" $0 "\047"}' ~/.todo/data
)
```

---

```
\047
```

is the octal ASCII representation of `'`

Comment: I'm having the same problem reading in filenames with spaces using find, how can I fix that?

Comment: I guess `$3=="task"` instead of `$4`.

Comment: @JohnLotacs, "There are tabs between columns, only spaces in column 3." makes no sense at all, spaces are **between** columns

Comment: This doesn't solve my problem, this is returning just the integer, I need the whole string, "task 3" "task 2" ... "baller"

Comment: the file is TAB separated, cut -f3 ~/.todo/data returns a column of strings "task 3\ntask 2\ntask 1\nballer", I want each line inside the bash array. I edited my question to be more specific.

Comment: Your update is still not quite right, you're searching for "task", "task" has no meaning, the string could be "do my homework", hence why the last item is "baller" it's just any valid string.

Comment: UPdated one more time ^^ It sounds really like I do your homework, yes. My snippet is easy to modify

Comment: I guess that should do it now